# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths (Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm getting the following error when I run Update-Database:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Comments_AspNetUsers_AuthorId' on table 'Comments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I'm very new to Entity Framework Core and databases in general and I have been wrestling with this issue for hours now.

My models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new();

    public List<Post> UpvotedPosts { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Comment> UpvotedComments { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Post> SavedPosts { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int Upvotes { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; } = new();

    public List<ApplicationUser> UsersUpvoting { get; set; } = new();
    public List<ApplicationUser> UsersSaving { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Upvotes { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUser> UsersUpvoting { get; set; } = new();
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Author)
            .WithMany(u => u.Posts);
        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Comments)
            .WithOne(c => c.Post);
        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(p => p.UsersUpvoting)
            .WithMany(u => u.UpvotedPosts);
        builder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(p => p.UsersSaving)
            .WithMany(u => u.SavedPosts);

        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Author)
            .WithMany(u => u.Comments);
        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.Comments);
        builder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasMany(c => c.UsersUpvoting)
            .WithMany(u => u.UpvotedComments);
        
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Posts)
            .WithOne(p => p.Author);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Comments)
            .WithOne(c => c.Author);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UpvotedPosts)
            .WithMany(p => p.UsersUpvoting);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UpvotedComments)
            .WithMany(c => c.UsersUpvoting);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.SavedPosts)
            .WithMany(p => p.UsersSaving);
    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried using `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)` like so:

```
builder.Entity<Comment>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Author)
                .WithMany(u => u.Comments)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

but I still get the same error.

Any amount of help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You are going to have to use `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)` on all of those relationships. You can't have any loops or multiple paths which have cascading delete.

Comment: Make a class or entity diagram and follow the relationships. That's basically all there is to it.